# is there any vim plugin to select block of code in any language?

Tags: vim

I mean, if my cursor is pointing somewhere inside of javascript else block, is there a plugin for one shortcut to be able to select all lines inside this else block, regardless to on which line exactly I'm currently in this else block pointing my cursor, so that, if I will want to select any other else block in, lets say ruby, using the same shortcut, I would be able to select the whole lines of this else block code in ruby?

thx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try <kbd>v</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> to select the "inner block", and <kbd>v</kbd><kbd>a</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> to select the block together with the enclosing braces.  See `:help text-objects` for more (highly useful) information.

Comment: well, it turns out this works just for javascript, as I tested. Not working for ruby as far as I can said.

Comment: @sandric: Did you read the help I pointed you to?  Ruby doesn't have blocks delimited by curly braces.  For more general text objects than the builtin ones see the [`vim-textobj-*` plugins](https://github.com/kana/vim-textobj-user/wiki) by Kana Natsuno, and the references there.  In particular: [vim-textobj-ruby](https://github.com/tek/vim-textobj-ruby).

Comment: thanks for pointing to those textobj related plugins, now I know where to look, thx